# How to make while loop run when a variable returns false?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

My code works without errors however if I type something random it still continues and does not print "Error" and rerun the code? How would I fix this?

```
gender = True
while gender == True:
    gender = input("Enter Gender: ")
    if gender == "Male" or "male" or "Female" or "female" :
        gender = False
    else:
        print("Error")
        gender = True
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `lower()`  and a correct `if` statement condition to fix the output error:

```
gender = True
while gender == True:
    gender = input("Enter Gender: ").lower()
    if gender in {"female", "male"}:
        gender = False
    else:
        print("Error")
        gender = True
```

Comment: No, no, no, no that is NOT the problem ...

Comment: + that’s not a dictionary

Comment: @azro What do you mean with your comment?

Comment: you said "use lower to fix" : no, the error is not about lower/upper. It's about operator precedence , as the duplicate link points out

Comment: @azro You're right, I'm going to edit the question

Comment: azro - would you be able to show me how you would run this code without using .lower()

Comment: @Tan7 did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true ? the duplicate that we point out

Comment: I just looked at that. Thank you